# Airflow Fail To Initialize DB

Tags: python-2.7, airflow, ubuntu-18.04

There is apache airflow installed and configured with mysql db without any errors.
The problem is when i `airflow initdb` or `airflow resetdb` the following error/exception is thrown

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-18 13:44:21.317153+00:00' for column 'last_scheduler_run' at row 1") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO dag (dag_id, is_paused, is_subdag, is_active, last_scheduler_run, last_pickled, last_expired, scheduler_lock, pickle_id, fileloc, owners) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ('example_skip_dag', 1, 0, 1, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 18, 13, 44, 21, 317153, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), None, None, None, None, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_skip_dag.py', u'airflow')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

How can i successfully run apache airflow 1.10.2

Comment: See [\[AIRFLOW-2459\]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2459)

Answer (score 2):

Just to recap for future users:

Stop the service:

```
systemctl stop mysql
```

Get the current state:

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
```

Add statement to the config without "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES":

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

under [mysqld]:

```
sql_mode="paste "select @@sql_mode;" output **without** STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"
```

Then start the service again:

```
systemctl start mysql
```